# Query for finding all occurrences of a string in a database

Tags: sql, where-clause, firebird

I'm trying to find a specific string on my database. I'm currently using FlameRobin to open the FDB file, but this software doesn't seems to have a properly feature for this task.

I tried the following SQL query but i didn't work:

```sql
SELECT
  *
FROM
  *
WHERE
  * LIKE '126278'
```

After all, what is the best solution to do that? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm using Firebird, I just fixed that. Thanks for warning me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do such thing. But you can convert your FDB file to a text file like CSV so you can search for your string in all the tables/files at the same time.

### 1. Download a database converter

First step you need a software to convert you databse file. I recommend using [Full Convert](https://www.fullconvert.com/howto/firebird-to-csv) to do it. Just get the free trial and download it. It is really easy to use and it will export each table in a different CSV file.

### 2. Find your string in multiple files at the same time

For that task you can use the **Find in files** feature of [Notepad++](https://notepad-plus-plus.org) to search the string in all CSV files located at the same folder.

### 3. Open the desired table on FlameRobin

When Notepad++ highlight the string, it shows in what file it is located and the number of the line. Full Convert saves each CSV with the same name as the original table, so you can find it easily whatever database manager software you are using.

Comment: i prefer to save the database into a single SQL script. Pro: you do not need "find in files" - it is ALL in one single file. Con: reading `INSERT` command might be harder than reading a row in CSV

Comment: And, yeah, technically he CAN "do such a thing", just it would rarely be the optimal approach to the problem, usually it would not be. However if for some reason that would be a program searching for the pattern, not a human, then SQL query might really be a way to go.

Answer (score 0):

Here is Firebird documentation: https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/reference_manuals/fblangref25-en/html/fblangref25.html

You need to read about

1. Stored Procedures of "selectable" kind,
2. `execute statement` command, including `for execute statement` variant
3. system tables, having "relation" in names.

Then in your SP you do enumerate all the tables, then you do enumerate all the columns in those tables, then for every of them you run a usual

```
       select 'tablename', 'columnname', columnname 
       from tablename 
       where columnname containing '12345'
```

over every field of every table.

---

But practically speaking, it most probably would be better to avoid SQL commands and just to extract ALL the database into a long SQL script and open that script in Notepad (or any other text editor) and there search for the string you need.